# right way to pass a boolean from controller to store a form data

Tags: php, laravel-5

i'm new to laravel and don't know what i did wrong.
i'm having this "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
syntax error, unexpected '='" whenever i try to submit my form.

this is in my create.blade.php

```
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="1" id="#is_available?" name="is_available?">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="is_available?">
    Is this available and ready to be rented?
  </label>
</div>
```

and in my CarsControllers.php

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $car = new car;

    $car->car_brand = $request->car_brand;
    $car->car_name = $request->car_name;
    $car->description = $request->description;
    $car->car_type_id = $request->car_type_id;
    $car->image_location = '';
    $car->is_available? = $request->is_available?;


    $car->save();

    return redirect('/selections');

}
```

The rest is okay except with that boolean. i don't know what to do. my column name is 'is_available?' to i have to change it?

Comment: Did you notice the question marks in `$car->is_available? = $request->is_available?;` I believe `php` is going to think that you are starting a ternary operand, try removing those, they have to be wrong.

Comment: sorry i pasted the wrong form. here it is

Comment: Nice edit, good job on that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must rename your form variable to `name="is_available"` because `?` outside of quotes will only be interpreted as the short hand ternary (you can check this blog post for more [Stitcher - Shorthand Comparison in PHP](https://stitcher.io/blog/shorthand-comparisons-in-php))

Additionally, in your controller you will need to remove all of the `?` in this statement `$car->is_available? = $request->is_available?;`

Finally, if your database field is also `is_available?` you will want to remove that `?` also.

Comment: Awesome, if you are satisfied with my answer, feel free to mark this question answered and welcome to StackOverflow, there's lots of help for Laravel on here.

Comment: i can't see where to click to mark this answered. sorry this is my first question here

Comment: Been a while since I asked a question myself, but I believe there's a check mark under the up/down vote that you click to mark it answered. [https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but change this line `$car->is_available? = $request->is_available?;`

to this `$car->{'is_available?'} = $request->{'is_available?'};`

Comment: hi thank you, but i already fix it by renaming my column, i removed the "?". again thank you for your response